# How to change Latexml DTD to NLM DTD 3.0?

Tags: conversion, xml

Am converting latex files to xml using latexml. The xml file which is created by latexml DTD is plain XML file. I need NLM DTD 3.0 in latexml for the conversion of tex files to xml. So is there any way to customize latexml DTD?

Comment: I suspect this is off topic here, but usually for this kind of transformation it is often best to first transform to an XML dtd that is close to the tex structure (the default latexml one) then to use xml tools such as xslt to transform from one xml vocabulary to another.

Comment: I am a beginner in XML. Could you tell me the steps how to customize the XML according to the tex structure or NLM DTD has the template which I need, so how to transform plain xml to NLM DTD structure.

Comment: Not really, like any translation it may be hard or easy depending on how accurate and general it needs to be, also it's way off topic for this site once it is an xml to xml question.

Comment: But I need to customize latexml then how could it be an off topic